# How to opening images on the same page?

Tags: php, photo-gallery

I have an album plugin (php) that creates thumbnails for my images in one page and when i click on images opens each image in a new page.
**Is there a way to opening images on the same page of thumbnails?**

This is my code of thumbnails:

```
    <div class="thumbs">

        <?php foreach (wppa_get_thumbs() as $tt) :  global $thumb; $thumb = $tt; ?>
                <a href="<?php wppa_photo_page_url(); ?>" class="img"><img src="<?php wppa_thumb_url(); ?>" alt="*" /></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
```

and this is the code of specific photo:

```
<?php } else if (wppa_page('single')) { // if is showing a specific photo ?>
    <a href="<?php wppa_photo_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php wppa_photo_url(); ?>" alt="<?php wppa_photo_name(); ?>" class="big" <?php echo wppa_get_fullsize(); ?> />
    </a><br />
<?php }  ?>
```

And this is the function that creates links:

```
// get link to photo
function wppa_photo_page_url($return = FALSE) {
    global $thumb;
    $url = get_permalink()  . wppa_sep() . 'album=' . $_GET['album'] . '&amp;photo=' . $thumb['id'];

    if ($return) {
        return $url;
    } else {
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the link code but does not work.

Comment: By 'on the same page' do you mean in a lightbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very easy to do using plain javascript's `Image` object. You can have a function that does something like this:

```
function load_image(image_path)
{
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = image_path;
   return image;
}
```

You can pull the url to the image from the link that they click on.

Then, append that image to a hidden div you have and make it visible. If you're using jQuery:

```
var image = load_image("/path/to/your/image.jpg");
$(image).appendTo("#your-image-div");
$("#your-image-div").show();
```

This is untested, but should work.

Answer (score 2):

The act of opening a link in a new window is usually associated with the "target" attribute of an anchor.  For example, this would put links in new windows:

```
<a href="wherever" target="_new">text</a>
```

But the code you've pasted above does not appear to include target attributes in , so I suspect the behaviour is controlled in your CSS, which you didn't include in your question.

Check your CSS files, and look for "target".  The W3C has [published documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/#target0) that describes how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jQuery plugin like [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) to *pop* the content dynamically over the current page.